# Server super slow after renewing SSL Cert? (IIS 6/.NET)

Tags: .net, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003, ssl-certificate

I am kind of stumped. Recently our sys admin updated our expired SSL cert. Afterwards, all of our forms authentication applications are performing very slow, very slow to log in, very slow to go to any pages. However our Windows auth apps have no such slowdown. We're talking 20 seconds or so to log in.

I checked the IIS logs, nothing amiss for error/status codes everything looks fine with the requests, all 200 0 0s. I recycled all app pools, and stopped/started IIS service, didn't help.

I don't even know if the SSL cert is causing the slow down but nothing else has changed, we rolled back all application updates to before the SSL cert expired, and that didn't help.

I am not sure what else to check to debug this. Does anyone have any ideas? We use .NET.

Using firebug .NET tab I see the following:

If I sit on the login page, and refresh, takes 128ms to load, no problems.

I enter in my login information and click login, it shows me a POST request on loginx.asp, status is 302 found, takes 20 seconds to process. After that it does a GET Default.aspx, also takes 20 seconds to process with a status of 200 OK.

Likewise the timeout occurs for each page a Navigate too, interesting enough the timeout is always around 20 seconds, is this indicative of something? Could this be a DNS issue?? It occurs over HTTP and HTTPS.

I am not sure if there is anything indicative in the Params/headers/post/response tabs for each request.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the timeline (under the net tab) in Firebug?

Comment: @SimonSvensson updated my post after checking this. Not sure if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: https://elgg.leeds.ac.uk/webteam/weblog/15385.html

Apparently the Network Service Account did not have NTFS permissions to the keys folder as well as the RSA and MachineKeys folder.

Comment: dead link. so what was fix?

Comment: It says right there, you need to make sure Network Service has NTFS permissions to where your SSL keys are stored, as well as the RSA and MachineKeys folders.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing anything that's slow on the server over a non-SSL secured connection? Also, seeing how you're using IIS6 [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295070) might potentially cause the issue.

Comment: Yes, over both http and https it's just as slow. I'll check that link.